# Which encryption/decryption to use with ECC?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

I'm using ECDH for generating shared key for STM32 MCU. Which encryption/decryption algorithm should I use? I looked at RSA and AES project samples provided by STM32 but where do I provide shared key with message to encrypt?

With the current implementation shared key size is 64 bits.

Comment: Do not use as reference any code that has a 64-bit shared key. That's very insecure by modern standards. Do not roll your own protocol (or use the protocol in a random piece of code), there are many things to miss.

Comment: If you're getting 64 bit shared secret, does that mean you also use 64 bit ECDH?

Comment: i changed my implementation to get 128 bits shared key

Comment: @minion: I trust you are using a larger (e.g. 256 bit) elliptic curve when doing the ECDH

Comment: @poncho - im using 512 bit elliptic curve